# Azure Pipelines Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching "/home/vsts/work/1/s/..." Error

Tags: dockerfile, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I want to build the dockerfile of the .net service in my repo using Azure Pipeline. The folder structure is as follows:

```
|-- ProjectA  
|-- |-- RepoB  
|       | -- .gitignore  
|       | -- Example.sln  
|       | -- Readme.md  
|       | -- Services  
|                 | -- ServiceC  
|                      | -- ServiceC.API  
|                           | -- Program.cs   
|                           | --     .  
|                           | --     .  
|                           | -- Dockerfile  
|                 | -- ServiceD  
|                      | -- ServiceD.API  
|                           | -- Program.cs   
|                           | --     .  
|                           | --     .  
|                           | -- Dockerfile
```

When I try to build the above dockerfiles with Azure pipeline, I get the following error::

`[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/Dockerfile  was found.`

azure-pipelines.yml content as follows:

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- test

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image for Lesson Service
      inputs:
        command: build
        buildContext: 'Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/**'
        dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Can you help me solve the error? Thanks for your help.

Yaml file can be run and find the Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the same with the folder structure and yaml:
[image]

To fix the error, you need to remove `buildContext` parameter, and define file path for `dockerfile`.

```
    steps:
    - bash: cat Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image for Lesson Service
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: 'Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

The pipeline works then:

[image]

The `buildContext` is useful when you have `containerRegistry` defined.

Answer (score 2):

Ok easy one,

So you have two parameters

```
    buildContext: 'Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/**'
    dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
```

Build context is where the build is going to essentially be built from and dockerfile is the location of the docker file.

When your pipeline gets to that task you will be executing from /home/vsts/work/1/s/ so your path to the docker file will be as below, if you a dropping the whole repo.

ProjectA/RepoB/Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile

But I am going to assume ProjectA is the Team Project and RepoB is the name of the git/TFVC repo, so not use is the pipeline folder drop.

Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile

Location on the build agent would be

/home/vsts/work/1/s/Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile

I wouldn't use wildcards in the buildcontext, I always set my build context at solution level, but it all depends on how you dockerfile is constructed.

```
- task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image for ServiceC
      inputs:
        command: build
         buildContext: 'Services/ServiceC'
        dockerfile: 'Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

You will then second task for the next dockerfile

```
- task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image for ServiceD 
      inputs:
        command: build
         buildContext: 'Services/ServiceD'
        dockerfile: 'Services/ServiceD/ServiceD.API/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

If you want both Services in a single container this is not the way to do it, but that is totally separate question.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But it gave the same error again. `Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/ProjectA/RepoB/Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile  was found.'

Comment: @oras see the comments above about team project name and repo name

Comment: Agree with @RickWeb. In addition, `buildcontext` is optional, you can even remove it but define Docker file with path `Services/ServiceC/ServiceC.API/Dockerfile` in the task. The buildContext is useful when you have containerRegistry defined.

Comment: @oras, i added the details in a new reply, thanks.